# Is it safe to change the power settings to allow raspberry 400 to power using usb?

Tags: pi-4, power, usb-power

I recently got a raspberry pi 400 and wanted to use it as a portable device but realised that it can only get full power when plugged into a power socket.

I saw a video showing that you can use it through usb but have to change the power settings in the boot config.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21A-1iAWW3Q

in boot/config.txt

over_voltage = -4

arm_freq = 1000

Is it safe to do this? if so what is the best settings to use?

Thanks
Shay

Comment: Pls tell us what changes you made so that we don't have to wade through a 20 minute video that probably only has a 5 second bit somewhere explaining what you did. Add relevant information to your query

Comment: Ah sorry will add it now